# How do you let a user choose the app database location?

Tags: c#, deployment, configuration, installer

Writing software for a client, and one of their requirements was that the user be able to specify where the application database is stored, be it on the local network or in an online repository.

I can let them choose where to put it, but how do I store that information in the application?

I guess I don't understand how to persist changes in an application that is already deployed. This is my first piece of software, so I've never been through the deployment process. Written in C# for Windows.

Comment: info about database location is to be stored in [Configuration file that can be modified by user in C#](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/191419/configuration-file-that-can-be-modified-by-user-in-c "see possibly duplicate question")

Answer (score 3):

For something like a target path, just use [Application.Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4s6c3a0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to persist it.

Comment: Thank you! I don't have enough rep to vote yet, appreciate the answer.